# Multi of 3 If else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

How do I do it if I enter a number that is a multiple of 3  it display the if statement for a number that isn't multi of 3 it goes to the else statement. I would be very thankful if you could help me.

```
        Console.Write("Enter Number: ");
        int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (N == 3) //<<< what do I do here
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is multi of 3");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is not multi of 3");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: N % 3 == 0  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple:

```
 if (N % 3 == 0)
     {
      Console.WriteLine("Is multi of 3");
     }
```

So Use:

```
 Console.Write("Enter Number: ");
 int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 if (N % 3 == 0)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Is multi of 3");
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Is not multi of 3");
 }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the modulus operator instead:

```
if (N % 3 == 0)
```

It returns the remainder after doing a division.

If the remainder of dividing by `3` is `0`, you know you have a multiple of `3`.